# Issue receiving messages in the fromApp method after sending a Quote Request Reject (35=AG)

Tags: quickfixj

I have an application that uses QuickFix version 4.4. In this application, we receive a Quote Request (35-R) and perform some validations. If any of the validations are not met, the application issues a Quote Request Reject (35-AG). The problem arises when this scenario occurs: subsequent Quote Requests (35-R) are not received by the fromApp method for processing, as if the application were blocked (although it continues to return administrative messages normally: fromAdmin and toAdmin). After a certain period, which can vary from 1 to 10 minutes, the application resumes normal processing. It's important to note that the Quote Request messages that are not processed by the fromApp method are still recorded in the database (JdbcLogIncomingTable) without any issues.

Comment: Create a thread dump during the period where it seems to be blocked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I collaborate with @Adan Vinicius

### Troubleshooting the Issue

During our investigation, we discovered the following sequence of events:

1. We sent a **35=AG** (Request Reject) message.
2. In response, we received a **35=Z** (Quote Cancel) message.
3. While processing the **35=Z** message, our application encountered a NullPointerException. Consequently, QuickFIX/J (QFJ) was unable to store this sequence number message in its FIX session control.

#### Handling the Missing Message

When we subsequently received a **35=R** (Quote Request) message, QFJ automatically sent a **35=2** (Resend Request). From QFJ’s perspective, a message was missing.

Interestingly, the **35=R** message was successfully stored in the QFJ log. However, our `fromApp()` method in our Application object was not being executed. This discrepancy caused confusion.

### QFJ Flow and Handling Invalid Messages

We made an important observation: when QFJ identifies an invalid message (such as an incorrect sequence number), it still persists that message in the QFJ log. However, the `fromApp()` method is not executed.

Comment: Good that you solved the issue. It was not clear from the original question what was going on. QFJ logs messages whenever it receives them. This happens in https://github.com/quickfix-j/quickfixj/blob/d7c9fe52fabdc56f28ace4063f6ac78fe422b511/quickfixj-core/src/main/java/quickfix/mina/AbstractIoHandler.java#L142 . Message parsing and processing is done later and only then is the message passed to the `Session` class where it is validated and eventually `fromApp()` will be called if validation succeeds.